# I want to populate my ContentView with data from an API but i'm getting a conversion error

Tags: datetime, xamarin.forms

The error message I'm getting

```
System.FormatException
  Message=One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
```

In my model, I have a getter and setter for the date I'm receiving as:

`public string date_sent {get; set;}`

and the value of date and time I'm receiving is `2019-11-19T16:09:32.000Z`.
In my contentView, I've my label as `<Label Text="{Binding date_sent}"/>`.

Comment: It looks all right to me. I thing you will have to elaborate a bit more on describing your issue. Try to isolate your bug and provide a simple sample where this can be reproduced. In that way other can better help you.

Comment: are you sure that's the field causing the error?  Since you're specifying it as a string, it's format shouldn't really matter.  Please post the code that actually causes the exception.

Comment: I don't really know what is causing the problem but the moment I deleted my contentView page, everything was fine. Then I had to set values manually to see if it works fine with another contentView Page which it does.

Comment: I test it in my project, I did not get the same error, can you upload your demo that could reproduce this issue to github?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to decipher the problem. The problem is with  the contentPage where I'm supposed to display the details for users. SO, all i did was to delete the contentPage then create another one

Answer (score 0):

Your data coming from Api contains date which is DateTime format, in order to display date you need to apply `StringFormat`.

Try this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding date_sent, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}'"/>
```

You can use other [c# Date Time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to display date as per your requirement.